# Sending URL via NFC to be opened by browser

Tags: android, url, nfc

I want to be able to send a URL via NFC so that it can be opened by the receiving phone's browser on android phones. Is this a possible action?

Comment: Only if the application ("browser") is configured/registered to do this. If you write your own browser you can support it, dont know about the standard android browser or chrome

Comment: Can't you already send links over NFC on default android broswers?

Comment: Yes, but I believe that this is the case when the browser is active. In your situation you want a registered application to open when the tag is read. I dont believe that the default browser supports this. I will have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After scratching my head for a few hours and browsing numerous posts. I found that all I needed to do was implement the NdefCallbacks and set the uri in the "createNdefMessage" method.

First implement the NdefCallbacks

```
public class MyActivity implements CreateNdefMessageCallback, OnNdefPushCompleteCallback {
```

Add the unimplemented methods

```
@Override
public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {  
    ...
}
...
@Override
public void onNdefPushComplete(NfcEvent arg0) {
    ...
}
```

Create an NFC Adapter at the top of your activity

```
NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;
```

Then setup the NFC Adapter in the onCreate method

```
mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
if(mNfcAdapter != null) {
    // Register callback to set NDEF message
    mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);

    // Register callback to listen for message-sent success
    mNfcAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(this, this);
} else {
    Log.i("LinkDetails", "NFC is not available on this device");
}
```

Then put the following in your createNdefMessage method:

```
return new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {
    NdefRecord.createUri(YOUR_URL_HERE)
});
```

Tap away, Android will handle the rest.

Thanks to the fine folks at [TAPPED](http://www.tappednfc.com/android-nfc-developer-guide/) for their guide, which got me about 3/4ths of the way to a successful NFC implementation.

Comment: Don't forget to add the NFC permission to your application manifest: ``<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>`` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#NFC

Answer (score 3):

Heck yes.

Put an NDEF formatted record containing the URL of the website onto the tag and you're done.

The Android SDK is *FULL* of examples.

Comment: Hi, would it be possible for you provide an example of this? I want to send an arbitrary url from 1 phone, wwwm.google.com for example

Answer (score 1):

Code blocks are from Android reference:

This is what you want to do, but you cant change the intent filters of the default Android browser.

> Reading NDEF data from an NFC tag is handled with the tag dispatch
>   system, which analyzes discovered NFC tags, appropriately categorizes
>   the data, and starts an application that is interested in the
>   categorized data. An application that wants to handle the scanned NFC
>   tag can declare an intent filter and request to handle the data.

These features are supported if apps are active supporting beam functionality:

> The Android Beam™ feature allows a device to push an NDEF message onto
>   another device by physically tapping the devices together. This
>   interaction provides an easier way to send data than other wireless
>   technologies like Bluetooth, because with NFC, no manual device
>   discovery or pairing is required. The connection is automatically
>   started when two devices come into range. Android Beam is available
>   through a set of NFC APIs, so any application can transmit information
>   between devices. For example, the Contacts, Browser, and YouTube
>   applications use Android Beam to share contacts, web pages, and videos
>   with other devices.

Do you see the difference between the two?

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Use these code, active android NFC Beam.

And most importantly is the "http://" prefix. I believe most of users tracked to this question stuck in this .

```
@Override
public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
    NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { 
        NdefRecord.createUri("http://www.google.com")
    });
    return msg;
}
```