# unable to send NFC URL via android enabled NFC Phone

Tags: android, url, nfc, message, ndef

I am trying to use NFC to send a URL from an Android app to other phone,
both have enabled NFC and working fine.

when i tried to test the app nothing happen,

i have tried the following app from store and it work perfectly:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxsoft.ndeftagemulator

this is my code:

```
 NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC not supported on this device.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

        nfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(event -> {
            String url = "https://www.example.com";
            NdefRecord ndefRecord = NdefRecord.createUri(url);
            NdefMessage ndefMessage = new NdefMessage(ndefRecord);
            return ndefMessage;
        }, this);

        nfcAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(event -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL sent via NFC.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(), this);
```

i also added permission in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

i searched for answers here and checked the following with no success ( android API +29 )

[Ho do I send a URL via NFC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014870/ho-do-i-send-a-url-via-nfc)

[Sending URL from Android to Windows Phone via NFC gives Play Store link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927395/sending-url-from-android-to-windows-phone-via-nfc-gives-play-store-link)

[Sending URL via NFC to be opened by browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326934/sending-url-via-nfc-to-be-opened-by-browser)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to substitute NfcAdapter.CreateNdefMessageCallback since android API level 29?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74351717/how-to-substitute-nfcadapter-createndefmessagecallback-since-android-api-level-2)

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't work, I want to emulate ntag213 URL once any other enabled device touch it to open in web browser.

Comment: the code perfectly worked after changing 

NdefMessage(createTextRecord("en", intent.getStringExtra("ndefMessage"), NDEF_ID))

to 

NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createUri(intent.getStringExtra("ndefMessage")))

in line 119 file KHostApduService.kt

Comment: sometimes it work sometimes it doesn't, the services exit

Comment: I've not tried that code myself for HCE, but HCE is the only way now to send data between devices as all the P2P NFC stuff e.g. `setNdefPushMessageCallback` you were trying to use was removed in Android 10. As well as that example there is a section in the Android Docs on HCE at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce